# Haskell: Why is extra space needed in arithmetic sequence for user defined enum?

Tags: haskell, user-defined-types

So for any built-in types in Haskell, I can construct an arithmetic sequence, like this one (for `Int` or `Integer`, etc.)

```
[1..5]
```

But if I define an enum type like:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade deriving (Show, Enum)
```

when I create an arithmetic sequence, I have to include space before an enum instance and the dot dot e.g.

```
[Club .. Diamond]
```

Why?

Comment: Note that this is a "range," not a "list comprehension."  A list comprehension is an expression like `[ f(x) | x <- myList ]`.

Comment: It's not a list comprehension, it's an [arithmetic sequence](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.10).  Apart from that, good question +1

Comment: Is this GHC specific?  Did you try other Haskell compilers?  This seems like a parsing oddity.

Comment: @HenriMenke It is not GHC-specific -- this is correct behavior according to the spec -- but nobody can deny that it is indeed a parsing oddity. To be honest, I'm a bit surprised this is the first time it's come up here on SO.

Comment: ...aha, it isn't the first time. =)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that, according to [Haskell's lexical rules](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4), `modid.varsym` is a reference to a variable in a module. A `modid` is a sequence of 1 or more capitalized identifiers separated by dots and a `varsym` is a symbolic name. `Club` is a valid `modid` and `.` is a valid `varsym` (note that there's even an operator in the Prelude with that name and that can be accessed as `Prelude..`). So `X..` is seen as the qualified name of a variable named `.` in the module `X`.

So `Club..Diamond` is tokenized as "qualified variable name, constructor name", not "constructor name, dotdot, constructor name"<sup>1</sup>. And when it tries to resolve the qualified variable name, it fails because there isn't an actually a module named `Club`.

The problem doesn't occur with `[1..5]` because `1` is not a valid module name, nor is there another way that `1..` or `1.` form a valid token. Note that, unlike some languages, `1.` is not allowed as a shorter way to write `1.0`. If it were, you'd run into a similar problem because `1..5` would now be tokenized as "number, dot, number". But it's not, so the problem does not occur.

---

<sup>1</sup> "Qualified variable name" wins out over "constructor name, dotdot" because of the maximum munch rule, which says that when there are multiple possibilities to match a token, take the one that matches the longest substring from the current position.

Comment: Am I mistaken or they wanted to get rid of this parsing oddity in Haskell 2010? (i.e. disallowing `X..` to mean variable `.` of module `X`, but forcing you to write `X.(.)` to mean that, which would get rid of this lexical issue).